# Expand all time steps between two dates

Tags: r, time

I have a sequence of events with start and end dates:

```
library(lubridate)
df<-tibble(StartDate=ymd_hm(c("2018-01-01 00:10","2018-01-02 00:20","2018-01-05 08:20"),tz="EET"),
       EndDate=ymd_hm(c("2018-01-01 00:10","2018-01-02 01:30","2018-01-05 08:30"),tz="EET"),
       Event=c("Event1","Event2","Event3"))
```

For each event I would like to have all 10 min occurrences. I can do this with loops and lists:

```
DateTime=list()
Event=list()
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  DateTime[[i]]<-seq(df$StartDate[i],df$EndDate[i],by="10 min")
  Event[[i]]<-rep(df$Event[i],times=length(DateTime[[i]]))
}

result<-tibble(DateTime=do.call("c",DateTime),Event=do.call("c",Event))
```

Desired output:

```
> result
# A tibble: 11 x 2
   DateTime            Event 
   <dttm>              <chr> 
 1 2018-01-01 00:10:00 Event1
 2 2018-01-02 00:20:00 Event2
 3 2018-01-02 00:30:00 Event2
 4 2018-01-02 00:40:00 Event2
 5 2018-01-02 00:50:00 Event2
 6 2018-01-02 01:00:00 Event2
 7 2018-01-02 01:10:00 Event2
 8 2018-01-02 01:20:00 Event2
 9 2018-01-02 01:30:00 Event2
10 2018-01-05 08:20:00 Event3
11 2018-01-05 08:30:00 Event3
```

But I am looking for a more delicate way, perhaps using tidyverse functions.

Please note that you might need to change "EET" with your system time zone in order for the example to be fully reproducible.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An option would be to use `map2` for getting the sequence between corresponding elements of 'StartDate' and 'EndDate', and then do `unnest`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  transmute(DateTime = map2(StartDate, EndDate, seq, by = "10 min"), 
            Event) %>%
  unnest  %>%
  select(DateTime, Event)
# A tibble: 11 x 2
#   DateTime            Event 
#   <dttm>              <chr> 
# 1 2018-01-01 00:10:00 Event1
# 2 2018-01-02 00:20:00 Event2
# 3 2018-01-02 00:30:00 Event2
# 4 2018-01-02 00:40:00 Event2
# 5 2018-01-02 00:50:00 Event2
# 6 2018-01-02 01:00:00 Event2
# 7 2018-01-02 01:10:00 Event2
# 8 2018-01-02 01:20:00 Event2
# 9 2018-01-02 01:30:00 Event2
#10 2018-01-05 08:20:00 Event3
#11 2018-01-05 08:30:00 Event3
```